# Android: compare json data with database

Tags: android, json, database, compare

in my Android app, I have a List of objects (Employees) obtained from a JSON on a server. Whenever I open the app, it parses the JSON, creates the ArrayList and populates RecyclerView. I would like to create a database and load the data from the database instead of JSON (so that it works offline as well and is faster).

My question is: how do I keep the database updated to make sure I have the same data in JSON and database?

What is the best approach to do this? I notice when I open the gmail app for example, it loads my emails even when I am offline, so it must be using a database as well.

EDIT: Solved it with using DBFlow and just calling save() on the whole list, which automatically decides whether to update a row or insert new one.

Comment: My suggest would be to just save the JSON as a file on your device. Read the file as a string and reload that with the parser that you already have to load the data to the RecycleView.

Comment: Obviously with the parsed JSON data you could update the database. You can compare however you like Strings are good for names, Strings or integers for ages or whatever. As you need. I think the gmail example should be removed as it conveys database and not comparing. That's two separate issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. Scenario "DB is empty": Show empty view message and fetch data from API endpoint -> save that to database and afterwards populate RecyclerView from database.
2. Scenario "DB not empty": Populate from database -> try to fetch new data, if there is no connection it still shows old data otherwise do steps from first scenario.

Additionally you could compare the custom class that populates the RecyclerView to prevent glitches while reloading same data.